Set a window minimum size to fit its contents
I am aware that Window has a SizeToContent property that when set to SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight keeps the window as small as it can to fit it's contents.
What I want to implement is a way to set a window's minimum size to this size. I investigated the code that uses the SizeToContent property to measure the window: Window.cs#L994 and saw that, to get this size I would need access to PlatformImpl.MaxAutoSizeHint, but that property is internal.
Is there another way to get this value? Or more generally, could I obtain the minimum size a UserControl would need to fit its contents?
Edit:
@Clemens suggestion works if you want the window to be at the minimum size when it's loaded, but if you need it to be at a different size, changing it after it is loaded leads to some weird results like misaligned controls.
Edit 2:
I accessed PlatformImpl.MaxAutoSizeHint through reflection and turns out it will not help on this.

You could set SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" on the Window and attach a Loaded event handler or override the OnLoaded method to set MinWidth and MinHeight and reset SizeToContent:
protected override void OnLoaded(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoaded(e);
    MinWidth = Width;
    MinHeight = Height;
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
}


That kind of works but it is not as flexible as I need it to be. I need to know ahead of time the size a control will need to be displayed properly.
